# Can I get all the performance metrics of an asp.net MVC 3 app from within the app itself?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, metrics, appharbor

So say I've got an MVC app hosted in the cloud somewhere, meaning I don't have access to IIS or any infrastructure.

All I have control over is the App code itself, and what comes down to the client.

### My goal

Is to collect data over time of how well the MVC app is performing in terms of response times.

### Current Problems

I can get a lot of data from Google Analyics, and other client-side tricks, but that won't tell if say, the App Pool is recycling too often.

Similarly if I put stop watches in the actions, that won't tell me about any delays in the App Startup (if it has to start up again).

Also, if I do put a stop watch in the Action, it doesn't take into account any delays in redering the View. For example, even though it's bad practice, there might be a DB call being made from the View, and my action metrics won't take that into account.

### My Question

So, if I want to get true metrics of how long requests are taking overal from mulitple clients and users, where are the best places to but Stopwatches in the App. Or is it impossible to get true metrics from the app itself, and I have to place counters outside of the App (like in IIS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add New Relic, it's available for free as part of the AppHarbor service - https://appharbor.com/addons/newrelic

Comment: Note that at the time of writing this comment, the New Relic is temporarily disabled for technical reasons.

Comment: thanks andy... but my question is more about understanding where to put the metrics myself in the app.

Comment: Learning where to put metrics is a hard.
  
I normally start with the external monitoring e.g. how long is the web server taking to respond to requests, how long is the DB taking to respond to the app etc. and then add more (e.g. DB Monitoring with something like DBTuna)  
  
Where you could start from is put metrics in where the external interfaces are i.e. to DB, to web server, to other services

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention "in the cloud somewhere" are you using Microsoft Azure for hosting? If so, there's some great diagnostics you can log to your Azure storage with [DiagnosticsMonitorConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee773149).

[Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2011/02/01/setting-up-performance-counters-in-your-web-and-worker-roles.aspx) a tutorial on how to add diagnostics to your web and worker roles. You can find a full list of performance counters on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411520.aspx)

You can get everything from application requests/second, memory and CPU utilization, network adapter statistics, output cache hits/misses, request execution time, etc.

Comment: hey thanks mfanto, but it's running on AppHarbor. I'm looking for a hosting agnostic way to measure performance. In App only. Is it possible?